# Listing (only) the subfolders within a folder -- Swift 3.0 / iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, subdirectory

I'm attempting to get a list of all subfolders within a folder (the app's `Documents` directory, in the example below).  The code below successfully finds everything in the folder (files + folders both), and also finds the files with the specified `.text` extension, but I'm failing to narrow the results to *just* a list of the subdirectories.

```
let filemgr = FileManager.default
var dirPaths = filemgr.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
myDocumentsDirectory = dirPaths[0]

var r = "Directory Listing:\n------------------\n" // r = will be returned (or displayed in this case)

do {
    let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: myDocumentsDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])

    // all files -- works fine
    let allFileNames = directoryContents.map{ $0.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent }
    r += "All file names:\n\(allFileNames)\n\n"

    // filtering for text files -- also works fine
    let textFiles = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "text" }
    let textFileNames = textFiles.map{ $0.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent }
    r += "text file list:\n\(textFileNames)\n\n"

    // Look for folders within the folder -- fails, nothing returned            
    let subdirs = directoryContents.filter{ !$0.isFileURL }
    let subdirNames = subdirs.map{ $0.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent }

    r += "Subdirectories:\n\(subdirNames)\n\n"
    textView.text = r

} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
```

I can pick up all the directories by setting the filter to

```
$0.pathExtension == ""
```

but that *also* picks up any files in the directory with no extension -- i.e. it correctly excludes `foo.bar` but incorrectly includes the file `foo` along with the folders, and that isn't what I need -- has to be **only** the directories & nothing more.

Also, I'm not trying to look deeper into sub-folders within sub-folders -- just the ones "here" is all I'm looking for.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated!

Comment: What a terrible API. Why do we have to write a bunch of extra ugly code to do something as basic as filtering out directories or filtering out files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass `URLResourceKey.isDirectoryKey` to the `includingPropertiesForKeys` parameter in your `contentsOfDirectory` method call on line 6. This should return that particular attribute for all your returned URLs. Then, you can check the attribute to see if each URL is for a directory or a file ...

If you are wondering how to get at the attributes for the fetched URLs, then take a look at the `resourceValues` method for the `URL` class :)

Answer (score 3):

Fahim's answer, specifically the `resourceValues` method for the `URL` class, is what I needed; for completeness & to help out anybody who finds this question later, here is the final code that gets exactly what I wanted, while keeping the same basic structure:

```
let filemgr = FileManager.default
var dirPaths = filemgr.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
myDocumentsDirectory = dirPaths[0]

do {
    let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: myDocumentsDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])

    let onlyFileNames = directoryContents.filter{ !$0.hasDirectoryPath }
    let onlyFileNamesStr = onlyFileNames.map { $0.lastPathComponent }

    let subdirs = directoryContents.filter{ $0.hasDirectoryPath }
    let subdirNamesStr = subdirs.map{ $0.lastPathComponent }

    // now do whatever with the onlyFileNamesStr & subdirNamesStr
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription) 
}
```